# Set Global Config on Angular Charts Not Working

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am trying to set ticks on the xAxis to begin at zero as a Global configuration option for Angular Charts and it doesn't seem to be setting the option:

```
.config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
                ChartJsProvider.setOptions( {
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            }])
```

Now I heard there might be a bug as well, so I tried this:

```
  .config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
            ChartJsProvider.setOptions("global", {
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you setting **beginAtzero** property its wrong. Because when you configure global setting for chart scale, there is no option for setting it for xAxes or yAxes. 
Try the below code for setting **beginAtZero**

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
    scale : {
        ticks : {
            beginAtZero : true
        }
    }
});
```